# Не добавляется value по кнопке, хотя код рабочий? Хотя в песочнице код работает

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, веб-программирование

При нажатии на кнопку, в input должно перейти ее значение. Но этого не происходит

jQuery:

```
$('button.size').on('click', function() {

    $('#item_size').val($(this).data('value'));

});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Новый</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/main.js"></script>

</head>
<body>


<div class="sizes">

    <button type="button" class="size" data-value="XS">XS</button>

    <button type="button" class="size" data-value="S">S</button>

    <button type="button" class="size" data-value="M">M</button>

    <button type="button" class="size" data-value="L">XL</button>

    <button type="button" class="size" data-value="XL">L</button>

</div>

<input type="text" name="item_size" id="item_size"/>

</body>
</html>
```

При нажатии на кнопку текст не отображается в input

[image: При нажатии на кнопку текст не отображается в input]

Comment: запускаю код и всё работает.... может ошибки в консоли есть?

Comment: Самое интересное, что у меня в codepen тоже работает. Дело в IDEA...почему такое может произойти?

Comment: а причём тут IDEA?))

Comment: запускаю в intellij idea и там проблемы. Хотя библиотеку jquery подключил

Comment: intellij idea - это же IDE для Java, как там можно javascript запустить? О_о

Comment: @АлексейШиманский intellij idea ultimate очень даже хорошо поддерживает javaScript. Я как раз в intellij idea разрабатываю. Однако согласен, как рабочий код и IDE связаны, не понимаю )

Comment: Можете показать, хоть скрином что ли, что именно за проблемы у вас в intellij idea с этим кодом?

Comment: Обновил вопрос,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас проблема не в IDE и не в коде, а в том, что ваш скрипт срабатывает быстрее, чем формируется DOM, поэтому на момент выполнения скрипта, элементов `$('button.size')` не существует.

> как решить

Обернем ваш код в функцию

```
function addListeners() {
  $('button.size').on('click', function() {

    $('#item_size').val($(this).data('value'));

  });
}
```

и будем вызвать ее после того, как HTML документ полностью сформирован:

```
<body onload="addListeners()">
```

И все будет замечательно работать

P.S.: Подтверждение IDEA
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: зачем так сложно......можно ведь делегирование сделать.... например `$(document).on('click', 'button.size', function()`

Comment: ...так я же написал

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Можно и так наверное ) Но мне кажется, перегружать событиями документ не самое правильное решение. Ведь само событие будет, как я понимаю, срабатывать на каждый тык мыши, но проверяться, а тык пришелся на нужный элемент или нет..

Comment: Ничего с документом не случится, если только пользователь не сидит на целероне первом с браузером IE5

Comment: @АлексейШиманский А вдруг это запустит тот... с ЭВМ :)

Comment: Спасибо вам!!!!!!!

Comment: Сделал все, как вы сказали, но результат все тот же - не может добавиться value при нажатии на кнопку...

Comment: @bodyauza Да ну не может быть. А что если заменить `<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>` на `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`. Может у вас в целом скрипты не подключаются?

Comment: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/main.js"></script>

</head>

<body onload="addListeners()">`
(js в файле main.js)
`function addListeners() {
    $('button.size').on('click', function() {

        $('#item_size').val($(this).data('value'));

    });
}`
 Так без изменений, даже не знаю, я в настройках библиотеку jquery подключал

Comment: Как вариант проверить, добавь в ddListeners первой строчкой `console.log('Я загрузился')` и посмотри в отладке, появится в консоле вывод?

Answer (score 0):

Все-таки не заработало, не знаю в чем причина:

```
function addListeners() {
    $('button.size').on('click', function() {

        $('#item_size').val($(this).data('value'));

    });
}
```

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-2.0.0.min.js">
</script>     
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/main.js"></script>
  </head>
 <body onload="addListeners()">
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]