# Не срабатывает скрипт при нажатии

Tags: javascript

Есть сам документ, при выборе в полях должен копироваться текс.
Сама страничка

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Копирование</title>
        <script src="copyscript.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Поля откуда брать</h1>
        
        <select id="select">
            <option value="#продажа ">#продажа </option>
            <option value="logic">#логика </option>
            <option value="value3">Option 3</option>
          </select>

          <input type="text" id="date" placeholder="дд.мм.гггг" pattern="[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" maxlength="10"/>
          <select id="clock1">
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
          </select>

          <select id="clock2">
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
          </select>

          
          <textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
     

          <button id="copy-values-btn">Copy values</button>


        
    </body>
</html>
```

И скрипт который и должен делать это копирование

```
    function buttonClickHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    copyValues();
    }
     var copyButton = document.getElementById("copy-values-btn");
    copyButton.addEventListener("click", buttonClickHandler);

function copyValues() {
    var selectValue = document.getElementById("select").value;
    var textareaValue = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
    var dateValue = document.getElementById("date").value;
    var clock1Value = document.getElementById("clock1").value;
    var clock2Value = document.getElementById("clock2").value;

    var combinedValue = selectValue + " " + dateValue + " " + clock1Value + - + clock2Value + "\n" + textareaValue;

    navigator.clipboard.writeText(combinedValue);

    alert("Values copied successfully!");
}
```

Когда я сам скрипт указывал в документе, и делал привязку кнопки через

```
<button onclick="copyValues()">Copy values</button>
```

Все отлично работало, но есть необходимость вынести скрипт в отдельный фаил, и видимо я не справился с привязыванием кнопки. Подскажите , что я сделал не так.

Comment: Оберните ваш код в отдельную фукнцию и вызовите ее после загрузки DOM дерева. [Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1491433/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-value-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%a5%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82/1491459#1491459)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого вам нужно подключать скрипт не в `head`, а в `body`:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Копирование</title>
        <!-- Тут я убрал подключение скрипта -->
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Поля откуда брать</h1>
        
        <select id="select">
            <option value="#продажа ">#продажа </option>
            <option value="logic">#логика </option>
            <option value="value3">Option 3</option>
          </select>

          <input type="text" id="date" placeholder="дд.мм.гггг" pattern="[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" maxlength="10"/>
          <select id="clock1">
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
          </select>

          <select id="clock2">
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
          </select>

          
          <textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
     

          <button id="copy-values-btn">Copy values</button>


          <!-- Тут я добавил подключение скрипта -->
          <script src="copyscript.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Проблема в том, что когда вы подключаете скрипт в `head`, DOM-элементы ещё не загрузились, и JavaScript не может найти элемент.